# Cordova: $.Ajax function is ignored

Tags: jquery, ajax, cordova

I'm working on an app which works great with the legacy hybrid build in Intel XDK.
But now I'm trying to build this in Cordova 3.5 from Intel XDK but all my ajax functions are ignored. No error, no success...

This is really strange because everything works great in the emulator but on an actual device the functions are completely ignored.

This is pretty much the logic that I use:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mobile/1.4.4/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="mobile/1.4.4/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.js"></script>

    <script src='cordova.js'></script> 
    <script src="intelxdk.js"></script>
    <script src="xhr.js"></script>
```

and the ajax function:

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            //url: 'http://localhost:60875/test.asmx/LogonUser',
            url: window.ajaxServer + 'LogonUser',    
            cache: 'true',
            data: {
                'username':get_cookie('username'),
                'password':get_cookie('password'),
                'environment':get_cookie('environment')
            },
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            beforeSend: function(){$.mobile.loading('show','a');},

            error: function(){
                $.mobile.loading('hide','a');
                self.loginUser_cb(jsonStr);
            },

            success: function(jsonStr){
                $.mobile.loading('hide','a');
                self.loginUser_cb(jsonStr);
            }
        });
```

As I said, everything works in Legacy Hybrid Native build, but not in Cordova.
Appreciate any advice,
Cheers!

Comment: Load the jquery after cordova.js

Comment: Hi Shammon, tried it with no success :/

Comment: show your ajax response

Comment: There is no ajax response. It doesn't enter the ajax function at all (in a Cordova build that is)

Comment: I'm still having this issue. Apparently it works on IOS but not on Android. I can't get my head around this problem